# how to color div by radiobutton/selectbox values

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I have the following situation here...

3 checkboxes(123)
1 selectbox
and 1 extra checkbox (4)

```
$("#checkbox8").change(function(){
setCheckbox();
});

$("#selecti").change(function(){
setCheckbox();
});

var setCheckbox = function() {
if ($('#selecti').val() == "501 - 1000" || $('#checkbox8').is(':checked'))
{
    if (!$('#lastcheck').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#lastcheck').click();
    }        
    $("#lastcheckdiv").attr("style","background-color:red");
}
else
{
    $('#lastcheckdiv').removeAttr("style");
}
```

};

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ry4k8ve9/4/)

I want that if a certain value in a selectbox or a certain checkbox is checked, another certain checkbox gets a red background.

In my case, when I check checkbox1, the checkbox4 turns red. But if I click another checkbox2/3, checkbox4 stays red. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code showing what you've tried.

Comment: Wrapping your JSFiddle link in a code block to surpass the warning about code needing to be included alongside JSFiddle links is breaking the rules. I've taken the liberty to comment out this link. Please edit your post to include the relevant code from your JSFiddle in the question itself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ry4k8ve9/4/ Sorry, I was about to edit the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the setCheckbox() function on every Checkbox change

Change

```
$("#checkbox8").change(function() {
setCheckbox();
});
```

to

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
setCheckbox();
});
```

And it will work

Or ... for a cleaner solution, give every checkbox that should vary the background color (1,2,3) a special class - like "colorSwitcher" and then do something like this:

```
$(".colorSwitcher").change(function() {
setCheckbox();
)};
```

And ... 
Demo (fixed):
http://jsfiddle.net/v39j52s0/5/

Comment: tHi Mandalorserbe, thanks for your time. In your Demo the checkbox 4 dont change rightaway, only after the second time :(

Comment: Gonna try to find a solution then I am home ... Cannt edit fiddles on my smartphone ...